# Windows Service Discovery - Extract executable from Path for Usage in Item Prototype

Tags: zabbix

I would like to discover Windows Services via discovery.service.

This works fine by default.

I would now like to create 2 more perf_counter item prototypes for CPU and memory utilization.

In Perfmon, however, I can only use the spoolsv instead of C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe.

{#SERVICE.PATH} from the discovery rule only provides me with the complete path to the .exe file.

Is it possible to shorten the path of {#SERVICE.PATH} so that only the name of the .exe file is passed?

Perhaps by means of preprocessing or overrides during the determination of the services.
I have already tried something here, but perhaps I am too stupid for regex.

Comment: You may be interested in https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/preprocessing . You would have to write javascript to transform the JSON returned by default to add another element to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I think this is above my skills.